# Python/Pygame - if statement troubles with .txt file

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame

I have an if statement that checks if a certain line of a .txt file is == "true" , but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.. Here:

```
configfile=open("FirstGameConfig.txt")
config_lines=configfile.readlines()
speed_of_object=float(config_lines[5])
acceleration_of_object=float(config_lines[7])
show_coordinates=str(config_lines[9]) #####
acceleration_mode=str(config_lines[11])
configfile.close()
```

This is all up top, and the show_coordinates string seems to be misbehaving down here:

```
font=pygame.font.Font(None, 40)
    if acceleration_mode=="true":
        speedblit=font.render("Speed:", True, activeblitcolor)
        screen.blit(speedblit, [0, 0])
        rectyspeedtext=font.render(str(abs(rectyspeed)), True, activeblitcolor)
        screen.blit(rectyspeedtext, [100, 0])
    if show_coordinates=="true":
        rectycoord=font.render(str(recty), True, activeblitcolor)
        screen.blit(rectycoord, [360, 570])
        rectxcoord=font.render(str(rectx), True, activeblitcolor)
        screen.blit(rectxcoord, [217, 570])
        coordblit=font.render("Coordinates: x=              y=", True, activeblitcolor)
        screen.blit(coordblit, [0, 570])
```

The script checks if acceleration mode is on. If the value for acceleration_mode is true then the speed of the object will be printed at the top left hand corner of the screen. activeblitcolor is already defined, so that's no problem.
What is under the if show_coordinates statement will print the coordinates of the object on the bottom left hand corner of the screen, assuming the value is "true" in the .txt file I have.

So the problem is that even though show_coordinates is set to true in the .txt file, this statement is skipped over. acceleration_mode is also in the .txt file, and it works perfectly. If the statement for checking if acceleration_mode is true works perfectly, why doesn't the statement for show_coordinates work the same? If I remove the if statement but keep the code that falls under it in the script, then the coordinates DO print in the bottom left hand corner of the screen like they're supposed to if show_coordinates == "true".

I certainly have "true" on the correct line in the .txt file. If I add "print(show_coordinates)" then "true" is the output. The script recognizes that the value for show_coordinates is true, but the if statement does not? Any help would be appreciated! I'm a beginner.

Comment: it would help if you post the txt file

Comment: Can you run this on the terminal and paste the output of "print(show_coordinates)"? Since you say that output is "true", I suspect a casting error is occuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readlines` method leaves the newlines at the ends of the lines.  I suspect your file does not have a newline at the end, and `acceleration_mode` is the last line, which is why that one works.

To verify my suspicion, add

```
print(repr(show_coordinates))
```

or even

```
print(config_lines)
```

You'll probably see that `show_coordinates` looks like `'true\n'`.

To fix the problem, you can add a call to `strip()` to clean up the strings. E.g.:

```
show_coordinates = config_lines[9].strip()
acceleration_mode = config_lines[11].strip()
```